# load more and more data when scroll down in Kartik Select2 widget

Tags: php, yii2, jquery-select2, yii-extensions, kartik-v

I am working on stock management system ,  with a large number of products  and the customer wan to display the products in a Select2 widget exactly like kartik widget, and he want to represent the data more and more when scrolling down ,is it available or can be done using this widget or I have to create my own ? 
this is my code

```
<?php
$url = Url::to ( [ 'products-list' ] );
echo Select2::widget ( [
    'name' => 'state_10' ,
    'options' => [
        'id' => 'select_product' ,
        'placeholder' => 'Select Product...' ,
        'multiple' => false ,
        'class' => ''
    ] ,
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true ,
        'minimumInputLength' => 1 ,
        'ajax' => [
            'url' => $url ,
            'dataType' => 'json' ,
            'data' => new JsExpression ( 'function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }' )
        ] ,
        'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression ( 'function (markup) { return markup; }' ) ,
        'templateResult' => new JsExpression ( 'function(product) { console.log(product);return product.text; }' ) ,
        'templateSelection' => new JsExpression ( 'function (subject) { return subject.text; }' ) ,
    ] ,
] );
?>
```

and I have this action in my controller and every thing is working well but I need to  start with displaying a number of  products in select2 and then  when scrolling start getting more and more

controller action :

```
    public function actionProductsList($q = null, $id = null) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $out = ['results' => ['id' => '', 'text' => '', 'qtyLeft' => '', 'serialNumbers' => '']];
        if (!is_null($q)) {
            $query = new Query;
            $query->select(['product_id as id', new Expression("CONCAT(product_name,' -- ',product_qty_left) AS text, product_qty_left as qtyLeft, s.serial_number as serialNumbers")])
                    ->from('product')
                    ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'serial_number s', 's.r_product_id = product.product_id')
                    ->where(['like', 'product_name', $q]);
//                    ->limit(20);
            $command = $query->createCommand();
            $data = $command->queryAll();
            $out['results'] = array_values($data);
        } elseif ($id > 0) {
            $out['results'] = ['id' => $id, 'text' => AppProduct::find()->where(['product_id' => $id])->one()->product_name];
        }
        return $out;
    }
```

Comment: hey, you need to update the server-side code for the `actionProductsList` function please see the update in my answer below

Comment: hello, thank you very much i was suffering from this problem which causes redundancy of the items retrieved from database, now i can say that every thing is going very well, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs to use pagination, you must tell Select2 to add any necessary pagination parameters to the request by overriding the `ajax.data` setting. The current page to be retrieved is stored in the `params.page` property.

So you need to change the `Select2` to the following

```
$url = Url::to ( [ 'products-list' ] );
echo Select2::widget ( [
    'name' => 'state_10' ,
    'options' => [
        'id' => 'select_product' ,
        'placeholder' => 'Select Product...' ,
        'multiple' => false ,
        'class' => ''
    ] ,
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true ,
        'minimumInputLength' => 1 ,
        'ajax' => [
            'url' => $url ,
            'dataType' => 'json' ,
            'data' => new JsExpression ( 'function(params) { return {q:params.term, page:params.page || 1}; }' )
        ] ,
        'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression ( 'function (markup) { return markup; }' ) ,
        'templateResult' => new JsExpression ( 'function(product) { console.log(product);return product.text; }' ) ,
        'templateSelection' => new JsExpression ( 'function (subject) { return subject.text; }' ) ,
    ] ,
] );
```

Select2 will expect a `pagination.more` value in the response. The value of more should be `true` or `false`, which tells Select2 whether or not there are more pages of results available for retrieval:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Option 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "Option 2"
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "more": true
  }
}
```

so modify your server-side code to include the `$page` param and include the `limit` and `offset` in your query. i am using 5 records as limit currrently you can change it.

```
public function actionProductsList($page, $q = null , $id = null ) {
        $limit=5;
        $offset=($page-1)*$limit;

        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        $out = [ 'results' => [ 'id' => '' , 'text' => '' , 'qtyLeft' => '' , 'serialNumbers' => '' ] ];
        if ( !is_null ( $q ) ) {
            $query = new \yii\db\Query;
            $query->select ( [ 'product_id as id' , new Expression ( "CONCAT(product_name,' -- ',product_qty_left) AS text, product_qty_left as qtyLeft, s.serial_number as serialNumbers" ) ] )
                    ->from ( 'product' )
                    ->join ( 'LEFT JOIN' , 'serial_number s' , 's.r_product_id = product.product_id' )
                    ->where ( [ 'like' , 'product_name' , $q ] )
                    ->offset ( $offset )
                    ->limit ( $limit );
            $command = $query->createCommand ();
            $data = $command->queryAll ();
            $out['results'] = array_values ( $data );
            $out['pagination'] = [ 'more' => !empty($data)?true:false ];
        } elseif ( $id > 0 ) {
            $out['results'] = [ 'id' => $id , 'text' => AppProduct::find ()->where ( [ 'product_id' => $id ] )->one ()->product_name ];
        }
        return $out;
    }
```

### `Update`

There were a few fixes that I found in the above code and changed

- Fix the offset `$offset=($page-1)*$limit;` rather than using the `$page` like `->offset($page)` use the `$offset` like `->offset($offset)`.
- Configure more results correctly to return false if no more results otherwise it keeps sending ajax calls to the server even if there are no more results so change it to `$out['pagination'] = [ 'more' => !empty($data)?true:false ];`

Comment: Thank you, every thing is going well now ! With appreciation !

Comment: happy to help @MohamadaliZayat